# What does a lower-case letter to the left of a term symbol, as in $\rm{a}\ ^7\rm{S}$, $\rm{z}\ ^7\rm{P^o}$, or $\rm{b}\ ^5\rm{D}$, mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, term-symbols

I'm a bit puzzled by this: the energy levels of neutral chromium (available by searching for `Cr I` in [the NIST ASD levels database](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html)), the term symbols generally have the form
$$
x\ \ ^{2S+1}L,
$$
where $x$ is a lower-case letter, in upright roman font in NIST's notation. Some examples are

- $\mathrm{a}\ ^7\mathrm{S}$ with a $4d^5(^6\mathrm{S})4s$ configuration;
- $\mathrm{z}\ ^7\mathrm{P^o}$ with a $4d^5(^6\mathrm{S})4p$ configuration;
- $\mathrm{b}\ ^5\mathrm{D}$ with a $3d^5(^4\mathrm{D})4s$ configuration;
- $\mathrm{y}\ ^5\mathrm{P^o}$ with a $3d^4(^5\mathrm{D})4s4p (^3\mathrm{P^o})$ configuration;
- $\mathrm{c}\ ^3\mathrm{D}$ with a $3d^44s^2$ configuration;
- $\mathrm{e}\ ^7\mathrm{S}$ with a $3d^5(^6\mathrm{S})5s$ configuration.

What does the lower-case letter on the left signify?

Comment: You may look here https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-spectroscopy-compendium-basic-ideas-notation-data-and-formulas/atomic-spectroscopy-2 in the last paragraph of the 'LS coupling' section and also here https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/Html/levelshelp.html#Top under 'term'.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. Yeah, I should've told myself to rtfm, but even then the explanation is still pretty cryptic. From what I can make out, the lower-case letters a,b,c,... are used as additional identifiers on term symbols that have *already* appeared (hence there's a bunch of a's, and the first b is on a term ^5D to distinguish it from the previous one, and the lower-case z,x,y,... are used for terms with nontrivial configuration interaction (i.e. multiple configurations contribute, as noted on the Leading Percentages column).

Comment: However, that doesn't explain why the $\rm b\ ^3D$ term has a beginning-of-the-alphabet letter but it still has a nontrivial configuration mixture on the right.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, your first link references [this book](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/NSRDS/nbsnsrds35v1.pdf), which explains the notation at the top of p. xii (p. 16 of the pdf), but frankly I have no idea what that paragraph actually means.